# Transitioning top and translate at the same time results in a misalignment that looks like mismatched easings (but isn't)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions, transform

I have some accordion-like elements that each contain an image of varying aspect ratio. My goal was to have those images completely cover the image area (centered absolutely) while the elements are closed, and when they're open, have the entirety of the images fit within the image area (a la `object-fit: contain`), top aligned. The images should smoothly transition between these two states.

[image]

In order to be able to animate between a "centered" state and a "top-aligned" state, I had to use absolute positioning, with the old

```
top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

the trick in order to center the images.

Flex would work for the start and end states, but it's not possible to transition between `align-items: center;` and `algin-items: flex-start`. The same goes for `object-fit: contain;`/`background-size: contain; background-position: top;`— the start and end states look as expected, but it's not possible to transition between them.

Now, I've got the start and end states achieved, and the images *do* transition between them, but I'm experiencing a weird effect.

---

The problem I'm experiencing is that when transitioning between

```
top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); //centered
```

and

```
top: 0; transform: translateY(0); //top-aligned
```

the easings don't seem to line up. For whatever reason, the image shoots past the goal of being top aligned, before settling in as top-aligned at the end of the transition. I've seent his happen before where maybe the timing-functions aren't the same, so one property's transition has started to decelerate before another has, making them fall out of step. But in this circumstance, both easings are the same (default): `ease-in-out`. Even if I try setting them to both be `linear`, which should negate any "easing misalignment", the issue still persists.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/GtwoK/pen/rNaamGE

Does anyone know what would be causing this? Are there other properties I should be transitioning to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Probably because the distances/sizes involved aren't related. One has less to travel than the other so the timing appears "off".